# querying a collection against a byte property in mongodb with c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am fairly new to mongodb and I am trying to query a collection with byte property but I am getting an invalid cast exception. To summarize,

```
public class MongoDbAddressCollection    
{
     private IMongoCollection<Addresses> collection = database.GetCollection<Addresses>("AddressCollection");
     public IEnumerable<Addresses> Where(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Addresses, bool>> filter = null)
     {
         var items = collection.AsQueryable().Where(filter);
         if (items == null)
             return null;
         return items.ToList();
     }
}

public class Test
{
    public void DoSomthingWithAddresses()
    {
         MongoDbAddressCollection addressCollection=new MongoDbAddressCollection();
         //exception occurs in MongoDbAddressCollection.Where method when executing the ToList().
         List<Addresses> homeAddresses=addressCollection.Where(x=>x.AddressType==(byte)EnumAddressType.HomeAddress);
         foreach(var address in homeAddresses)
         {
            //do stuff
         }
    }
}
```

And the address entity is as following class

```
public class Address
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public byte AddressType { get; set; }
    .....
}

public enum EnumAddressType
{
    HomeAddress=1,
    WorkAddress=2
}
```

Actually the issue seems to be a type mismatch between mongodb and .net, I can see that the AddressType for WorkAddress entities is 10 which is binary representation of 2. But, I cannot think of a solution other than changing all byte properties in all of our entities to int before I insert them to collections (we have lots of byte properties in different entities)... Or can this be fixed with a workaround in the query (linq where condition)?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a problem with the serialization of `byte` type. I think the fastest solution would be to change the type of `AddressType` property from `byte` to `EnumAddressType`

```
public class Address
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public EnumAddressType AddressType { get; set; }
}
```

And write your filter without casting:

```
var filter = Builders<Address>.Filter
    .Where(x => x.AddressType == EnumAddressType.HomeAddress);
```

You can test your filter using this method:

```
public static BsonDocument RenderToBsonDocument<T>(FilterDefinition<T> filter)
{
    var serializerRegistry = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry;
    var documentSerializer = serializerRegistry.GetSerializer<T>();
    return filter.Render(documentSerializer, serializerRegistry);
}
```

The result

```
var json = RenderToBsonDocument(filter).ToJson();
// Result: { "AddressType" : 1 }
```

As an alternative approach, you can write your custom byte serializer and register it using:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Address>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.AddressType).SetSerializer(MyCustomByteSerializer.Instance);
});
```

You can see a [sample serializer code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Serializers/BsonInt32Serializer.cs) here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mennan. Changing the property type to enum is not really an option because the property corresponds to a tinyint column in the database and the entity is auto generated... I tried the custom serializer and the data is fine in mongodb now but I am still getting an exception when I am executing the Where(filter).ToList() method.